# In terms of a using a CableCARD with Windows Media Center, what is the Product Key and Host ID, and how do I find them?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I have a Windows 7 PC hooked to an HDTV via HDMI. Connected to the PC are a [CableCARD tuner](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_dcr2650.html) and a [tuning adapter](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sta1520), each via separate USB ports.

While going through the TV Signal setup in Windows Media Center I get stopped here:
[image: A lousy dialog message of the likes that MS promised to do away with in Windows 7]

I called the cable company, hoping they would have one. Now, I don't want to confuse matters even more, but after explaining what I was looking at, the tech told me to give him my Host ID and then we would be able to get past this. I was under the impression that he would enter the Host ID somewhere, and then I just wouldn't see this screen anymore.

He told me to look on my CableCARD tuner, it's not there.

So, what are these two items I'm being asked for?

Comment: Did you try running the [Digital Cable Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Digital-cable-tuners-frequently-asked-questions#) (more than once)?

Comment: @techie008 Yes, no dice.

Comment: Also, it could take many minutes (20+) for the card to become Activated from their end.  If the rep. you spoke to did it just then, it make take a while.  Once it has been activated from their end, and you run the DCA, it shouldn't ask you for that code.

Comment: Okay, a different tech told me he can't activate it unless I give him the host id. He also said the product key is for Windows Media Center, and he doesn't know why I'm being asked for one as it should fill in automatically.

Comment: Was this a fresh isntall of Windows 7 when it was done?  Do you have a valid Windows 7 key you could try?   There seems to be a 'generic' key around for this situation (available with a little searching), but I'd rather not provide that here.  Instead, perhaps contact your computer manufacturer, or MS?  Microsoft phone support is free for activation problems. Or perhaps someone will come along with a direct answer/solution. :)

Comment: @techie007 Yes, actually it's a genuine, well maintained system. When I read about pirated copies automatically bypassing that screen, I decided to go  with the "Generic Windows Media Center Activation Key" that's floating around. Someone told me it's the key Microsoft gives to cable operators for their users, so I decided to roll with that. The next screen gave me my Host ID, and I was able to activate the CableCARD over the phone with my cable company. I think your last comment is a good answer. Very happy thanks! http://i.imgur.com/fsH7W.jpg

Comment: I thew it into an answer.  Perhaps not much of one but apparently it helped. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

Did you try running the Digital Cable Advisor (more than once)?

Also, it could take many minutes (20+) for the card to become Activated from their end. If the rep. you spoke to did it just then, it make take a while. Once it has been activated from their end, and you run the DCA, it shouldn't ask you for that code.

Was this a fresh install of Windows 7 when it was done? Do you have a valid Windows 7 key you could try? There seems to be a 'generic' key around for this situation (available with a little searching), but I'd rather not provide that here, but if you can find it (not hard) perhaps give it a shot?

Otherwise, perhaps contact your computer manufacturer, or MS? Microsoft phone support is free for activation problems.